# Date is printing but failed to evaluate as not empty in jstl

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, jstl

I am using JSTL to iterate Spring model values in my JSP.
I display the two dates in my JSP using JSTL.

Below is my Java code:

```
model.put("oldest",timesheetService.getOldestPendingTimesheet(userDetails));
model.put("pending", timesheetService.getNextOldestPendingTimesheet(userDetails));
```

JSP Code:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${not empty model.oldest}">
        <c:out value="${model.oldest}"/>
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${not empty model.pending}">
        <c:out value="${model.pending}"/>
    </c:when>       
</c:choose>
```

I display the both dates in outside the `c:choose` it printing like below

```
oldest:Tue Nov 04 00:00:00 IST 2014 
Pending:Sun Nov 09 00:00:00 IST 2014
```

Oldest Date is printing inside the `c:when`, but pending is printing only outside the `c:choose` and not printing inside the `c:when`.

What's wrong with the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because when you have several `<c:when>` in `<c:choose>`, the first one is interpreted as `if` and all the others as `else if`. So, your first condition is satisfied and the second `when` is ignored.

If you want to print both of them depending on non-exclusive conditions, better use `<c:if>`. It is also easier to read than `<c:choose>` construct, when you have few conditions.

```
<c:if test="${not empty model.oldest}">
    <c:out value="${model.oldest}"/>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${not empty model.pending}">
    <c:out value="${model.pending}"/>
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `<c:choose>` works like a Java `switch` statement. It lets you *choose* between a number of alternatives. Where the `switch` statement has `case` statements, the `<c:choose>` tag has `<c:when>` tags. So, if the one of  `<c:when>` satisfies a condition then others `<c:when>` will not execute, like if you put a `break` condition after `case` block. You should use `<c:choose>` if you want to print either of properties. If you want to print them both then you'd better use `<c:if>` to test for emptiness. If you want still to use `<c:choose>` then you need it to do in a separate tags. Also for formatting a date use `<fmt:formatDate>`

```jsp
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${not empty model.oldest}">
         <fmt:formatDate type="both" 
            dateStyle="long" timeStyle="long" 
            value="${model.oldest}" />        
    </c:when>
</c:choose> 
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${not empty model.pending}">
         <fmt:formatDate type="both" 
            dateStyle="long" timeStyle="long" 
            value="${model.pending}" />
    </c:when>       
</c:choose>
```

Comment: Thanks Roman It's worked for me,Is their anything like if-elseif-else in jstl?

Comment: No, only choose-when-otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Another option can be -

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${not empty model.oldest}">
        <c:out value="${model.oldest}"/>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <c:when test="${not empty model.pending}">
            <c:out value="${model.pending}"/>
        </c:when>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```